# Crash on first launch of sandboxed app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I just changed my sandboxed app's bundle identifier, and ran it. I get a runtime exception before `main()` even runs. The top of the stack trace is `runtime_init`. I tried running the app outside of Xcode and got the standard crash report dialog. Scrolling through the information presented, I noticed:

```
Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, running initializers
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
xpchelper reply message validation: sandbox creation failed: 1002
Container object initialization failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 13.)
```

As soon as I run another time, there's no problem. I see that the container exists. As soon as I remove the container, though, the exception gets thrown again. I don't want my users' first experience with my app to be a crash. How can I fix this?

I tried repairing permissions, which made no difference. I also noticed that by the time Xcode breaks on the exception, the container has already been created. Also, Craig Hockenberry mentioned this error in a [blog post](http://furbo.org/2012/01/23/sandboxing/), but he blamed symlinks in the user's Home directory. I don't have any symlinks there (not in the top level, at least, which is what I assume he means).

Additional input [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/jgreenfield/status/208954966482755584) suggests that it can be a symlink *anywhere*, in which case I definitely do have some. Has anyone discovered a workaround for it? I suppose that would be tough, as no application code executes before the exception. Hopefully Mountain Lion will fix it...?

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this crash by removing everything from the Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Movies, and Pictures user directories.  I assume it's related to the sym link issue mentioned in other threads.

Comment: I understand that that is what's causing the problem, as mentioned in my question. What I'm looking for is a solution that won't require my users to manually clear out any symlinks from their home folders.

Comment: I check for the missing file(s) and then prompt the user to check an online support article or contact support.  The online article describes how to locate the appropriate container directory and create / move the necessary directories and files.  Less than ideal but works so far.